# Laravel 4 - Using multiple paginators on one page

Tags: php, laravel-4, pagination

I've been googling for this question but can't find any good answers. I found that there is a method called `setPageName()` for the paginator but it only works when used like `Paginator::setPageName('page')`.

I looked up the paginator in the Laravel API (http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Pagination.Environment.html) and the method is a public function just like setBaseUrl which I am currently using like `$albums->setBaseUrl('/album/');`

for instance I want to have a Photo paginator (?photoPage=n) and a Comment paginator (?commentPage=n).

Is there any way that I can use two paginators that use different page names in the URL on one page, or at least call the `setPageName()` method like `setBaseUrl()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are actually two classes at play here:

- [`Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/e60ea917ab862254a6db37fa9cb8933138c1e73c/src/Illuminate/Pagination/Paginator.php)
- [`Illuminate\Pagination\Factory`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/e60ea917ab862254a6db37fa9cb8933138c1e73c/src/Illuminate/Pagination/Factory.php)

Where the `Factory` class actually orchestrates the creation of `Paginator` instances.  After a quick glance, I couldn't really tell you why the `Factory` class is in charge of `get/setPageName()`, but [that's where they live](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/e60ea917ab862254a6db37fa9cb8933138c1e73c/src/Illuminate/Pagination/Factory.php#L171-L190).

It seems that you would need two distinct `Factory` instances, which, fortunately, is possible via the IoC Container.  Since the [`PaginationServiceProvider`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/e60ea917ab862254a6db37fa9cb8933138c1e73c/src/Illuminate/Pagination/PaginationServiceProvider.php) binds to `paginator`, calling `$app->make("Illuminate\Pagination\Factory")` twice should generate two distinct factories.  If you're using namespaces, a service provider to inject the factories into your controller might look like:

```
class DoublyPaginatedControllerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {
    public function register($app)
    {
        $this->bindShared('paginator.photos', function ($app) {
            $factory = $app->make('Illuminate\Pagination\Factory');
            $factory->setPageName('photoPage');
            return $factory;
        });

        $this->bindShared('paginator.comments', function ($app) {
            $factory = $app->make('Illuminate\Pagination\Factory');
            $factory->setPageName('commentPage');
            return $factory;
        });

        $this->app->bindShared('Namespace\DoublyPaginatedController', function ($app) {
            return new DoublyPaginatedController(
                $app['paginator.photos'],
                $app['paginator.comments']
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, the downside here is that you can't use Eloquent's `Model::paginate()` -- you'd need to manually determine which set of items to get and pass them to each Factory's `make()` method.

Comment: So in other words, making a manual paginator would be easier? Thanks for the good and thorough answer!